# How can we gracefully convince people to upgrade their environment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, vote-to-close

In the [`delphi`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi) tag, it's very common to see people who are trying to rely on older technology rather than trying to grasp the modern ways. Such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58176790/tserversocket-how-check-if-a-specific-client-on-listview-still-is-connected-bef).

As noted, the technology involved is extremely out of date, yet people continue to try and use it for modern production. Rather than just shifting to the latest in the IDE (which the tech they're using is no longer installed by default, and requires it to be explicitly installed to use).

How exactly should we respond to people who are stuck in an outdated environment and somewhat convince them they're living in the old days - without being too blunt?

Comment: You can suggest it once in a comment and move on. While recognizing these people *may have no other choice*, for a variety of reasons you can’t and won’t know. If you mention it in an answer, make sure to *also* still answer the question as asked with the existing technology as a constraint you can’t negotiate.

Comment: Related: [How to handle questions where the answer is to upgrade to a newer version?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379121/7795130)

Comment: Related: [Is it proper to inform users that their Python 2 questions will soon become obsolete?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389704)

Comment: @DanBron your comment is actually an answer so please make it an answer so the community can handle it appropriately.

Comment: Some may work on legacy systems where it is not economically viable to make changes to the entire code base just to accommodate a new version of the compiler (I don't know if that is the case for Delphi). And for the very conservative and risk-adverse minded, risk breaking the system by a compiler update and/or framework (this very seldom happens in practice, though. ).

Answer (score 31):

You *don't*.

You have been presented with a question that has some incredible constraints to it.  If you can answer within those constraints, you delight the OP and any others who have to live with those constraints.

If you try and convince them that they should (or need) to upgrade, you're not really accomplishing much; they may have a valid reason to be forced to use that version of the software, and your comment about the technology being out of date does little to soothe the immediate pain of *having to use the technology*.

So...if you can answer it with the constraints presented by the OP, then do so.  If you can't, then it'd be best to hold your tongue and wait for someone else to answer the question.

Answer (score 11):

I was stuck with very old Java tech for years of my life... not because I was into making my life hard or because I was too stupid to realise it. It is because the existing code base heavily relied on it and active development time all went into bug fixing and new features.

Upgrading tech has costs in a business environment; it costs time, it introduces faults, it requires planning, it uses manpower and more importantly it halts other planned work. After the upgrade you essentially end up with a product which is still the same, at least that's how people will perceive it. It all depends on if there is a person available that can properly rationalise those costs to the people who decide the budget if it is going to happen - and maybe another person to properly manage the project(s) that will need to happen to get it done.

Stack Overflow should be a place you can go to when you do not have the liberty of doing what would be ideal; being stuck with old tech should not alienate you from the site. We're not all so lucky unfortunately.

Comment: Updating may result in a higher quality product (e.g. higher robustness due to a more strict compiler, with more error checking). Compiler bugs may also have been fixed (though that usually only applies to some extreme edge cases).